# How do I delete the "Tab Group Favorites" bookmarks group in Safari?

Tags: safari, tabs, bookmarks

How do I delete the Safari "Tab Group Favorites" bookmark group? (I don't mean the "Favorites" folder).

It shows up in my Bookmark sidebar. I don't even know how it got created. It contains folders I no longer want. And I can't rename anything within the group either. If I right-click the group or any of the folders within, I'm presented with a "Open in Tab Group" option. There's no delete option.

I searched online for an answer and didn't find anything. Is there a way to edit the .plist and delete it that way? Thanks.....

Comment: Are you on Mac? Could you provide a screenshot of what you want to delete exactly?

Comment: See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254225610?answerId=258190702022#258190702022

Answer (score 0):

"Tab Group Favorites" is automatically created by Safari when you create a tab group.

If you delete a tab group in the "Tab Groups" view, the corresponding folder in "Tab Group Favorites" will be automatically deleted Safari. You cannot delete the folder manually.

"Tab Group Favorites" will be empty if you do not have any tab group, but "Tab Group Favorites" itself cannot be deleted.

BTW, "Tab Group Favorites" can be used to add bookmarks/links in the start page of the group. <sup>[1](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/14fro5e/comment/jp1zhyk/)</sup>